# How to close an absolutely positioned window created with the ":target" pseudo-class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/jh1nwgyL/1/embedded/result/

I'm made this cool 'modal' only with CSS3 `:target`, but when i choose one option, the modal will disappear and the button 'Criar evento' will not work anymore, i want fix that, but i'm with difficult , I've tried changing the display element, using `hide()` and `show()`, nothing works!

I want to be able to pick an event, make the 'modal' disappear but not change the functionality of the button..

HTML:

```
<a href="#new__event" class="create__event">Criar evento</a>

<div id="new__event">
        <a href="#" class="close"></a>
        <div class="targets">
          <div class="target" data-id="free">
            <h2>Free Pass</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="target" data-id="augusta">
            <h2>Augusta</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="target" data-id="vila">
            <h2>Vila Madalena</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="target" data-id="custom">
            <h2>Personalizado</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
#new__event {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
#new__event:target {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
}
#new__event .targets {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#new__event .target  {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 48px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: white;
  color: #f98835;
  margin-top: 0.1rem;
}

#new__event .target:hover {
  background: #f98835;
  color: white;
}
#new__event a.close {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #34495e;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
#new__event a.close:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.target').on('click', function () {
    var page = $(this).data('id') + '.html';

    $('#new__event').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the URL hash by changing the value of `window.location.hash`.

In doing so, the `:target` pseudo-class isn't active (which is what is making the `#new__event` element visible).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/t133vac3/)

```
$('.target').on('click', function () {
     window.location.hash = null;
});
```

As a side note, when you click on the anchor element,

```
<a href="#new__event" class="create__event">Criar evento</a>
```

The `window.location.hash` value is changed to `new__event`.